# Getting notification twice for same event in chat messages

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using the below code for the notifications in a chat messaging, it is executing successfully, but it is executing notification twice for the same event, which should happen only for once for a single event. May I know what wrong I am doing in the code below for the firebase cloud function implemented with firestore database in flutter application

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document("messageRoom/{message_room_id}/messages/{messageID}").onWrite((change, context) => {
    const idTo = context.params.idTo;
    const message_room_id = context.params.message_room_id;
    const messageID = context.params.messageID;


    return admin.firestore().collection('messageRoom').doc(message_room_id).collection('messages').doc(messageID).get().then(queryResult => {

            const idFrom = queryResult.data().idFrom;
            const to_token_id = queryResult.data().to_token_id;
            const idTo = queryResult.data().idTo;

            console.log("User id " + idTo + "   | Notification id " + "notification_id" + "  | Token ID is : " + to_token_id + " | from user id  " + idFrom);

            var payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: 'Chat Message',
                    body: "New Message",
                    icon: 'default',
                    sound: 'default'
                },
                data: {
                    click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                    groupChatId: messageID,
                    category: 'default'
                }
            };

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(to_token_id, payload).then(result => {
                console.log("Notification Sent chat notification");
                return null;
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: My first thought is that your onWrite listener is getting called twice. Make sure you are only writing to messageRoom/{message_room_id}/messages/{messageID} once, whether it be from a device or another cloud function. Good luck and lmk if you find anything.

Comment: @SanzioAngeli, got it, actually I am writing to two different locations at the same time that's the reason  I am facing this issue, thanks

Comment: Nice. happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just thought that this is worth an answer creation basing on Sanzio and Johnny convesation.

In such situation first thought is that `onWrite` listener is getting called twice. So first to make sure writing to `messageRoom/{message_room_id}/messages/{messageID}` is done once, whether it be from a device or another cloud function.

Actually, in this case it appeared that  writing has been done from two different locations.

I hope it will help anyone who will face it in future :)